# Angular 6 route path not working for direct url when deployed in subdirectory

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

app.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './public/home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: '../app/customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: '../app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',    
    redirectTo: 'home',    
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

These works fine under the **Development environment**.
If I directly open `localhost:4200/home` then it's landing on the expected page.

However, the one **built** and **deployed** using with `ng build --prod --base-href=/myngapp/` do works only on `www.domain.com/myngapp` if I open the `www.domain.com/myngapp/home` directly, then it gives 404 not found error.

Comment: try `{ path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }` in routes.

Comment: but my target path is `www.domain.com/myngapp/home` then why to keep the `path:''` empty match?

Comment: `/myngapp/home` gives 404 error, so, what does `/myngapp` show? Home page?? In this case,you home page is somehow mapped to `/myngapp`, may be due "**", You need to analyse your url maps for other pages, like admin, and provide more precise error.

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal you can check the existing live url: https://angular6demoamit.000webhostapp.com/home . it gives 404 not found default page of the web hosting site i think.

Comment: does the same problem exist on localhost, if no, the problem might be with server, I guess

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal, yes the same issue when I deploy it under wamp server subdirectory in my local machine. but regarding your 1 comment answer: why we need to match it with the empty path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174344/discussion-between-amit-shah-and-abhishek-jaiswal).

Comment: Open index.html file in dist folder and set base path  `/myngapp/`  in head.

Comment: @KaranPatel it's there already.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to setup proper URL rewriting rules. Angular docs explains how to do it for most popular http servers. You can find details here.

https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

What it do, is to simply speaking, tell server to always serve index.html no matter what is the path of the request. eg.

`www.domain.com/myngapp/home` -> serve index.html, not home.html or something similar
`www.domain.com/myngapp/some/child/routing` ->serve index.html and dont try to find some/child/routing.html or php and so on.

Answer (score 5):

You must configure your HTTP server(apache, Nginx or others) to redirect all URI which began with www.domain.com/myngapp/** to the index.html file.

Notice the routes of your application (https://angular6demoamit.000webhostapp.com/) works fine when they are accessed "inside Angular" by interaction with buttons and menus. However, when you try to access the route typing it directlly on the browser, the server doesn't know the URI https://angular6demoamit.000webhostapp.com/home is a route of an Angular application. It'll probabilly try to load the index page of an inexistent home directory.

There isn't a single configuration to solve your problem. It'll depend on your HTTP server and infraestructure. Read the guide of angular which describes some configurations examples to some kinds of HTTP servers: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml.

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue. if it's working fine in localhost, then you should try this solution.
Maybe adding URL rewriting rules in your .htaccess file solve your problem. I found it on
http://joeljoseph.net/angular-6-deploy-on-apache-server-by-solving-404-not-found-error-on-page-refresh/

Add this into your .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

for more detail go to http://joeljoseph.net/angular-6-deploy-on-apache-server-by-solving-404-not-found-error-on-page-refresh/

Answer (score 1):

If you copy the files into a server sub-folder, append the build flag, --base-href
like if you have index.html file on server /myngapp/index.html then add command with  build --base-href=/myngapp/ else copy all dist file and paste on server without base-href.

Comment: that's not my question, as I already mentioned I am deploying it under the subdirectory and I am building it with -bh flag.`

Answer (score 0):

For reference, I'm using Busybox httpd and having the following in httpd.conf worked surprisingly well

```
E404:index.html
```

It means send index.html when there's a 404 error. When I directly goto a path it actually loads the page in the path. I was expecting it only shows index page but it self-navigated to the path in url.

I'm using Angular 9

https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/networking/httpd.c

Answer (score 0):

If can be fixed by setting the htaccess file.
We assume that our single page app is running on a subdirectory on the server .

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /   
 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
 
  # Rewrite everything of to index.html
  RewriteRule ^sub_folder/(.*)$  sub_folder/index.html  [NC,L]                             
</IfModule>
```

Explaining:
We assume that the app is located in /sub_folder.
We config htaccess to redirect to the index.html file for any url containing sub_folder.
May it helps someone.

Answer (score -3):

Try using:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'customers',
    loadChildren: '../app/customers/customers.module#CustomersModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: '../app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: '**',    
    redirectTo: 'home',    
  }
];

imports: 
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})
```